# Raspberry Pi static IP failed. how can I get dynamic back

Tags: failure

My laptop uses wifi, and Pi is connected to router via cable. With the dynamic IP, it worked well with Putty on my windows 7.

Then trouble came after I changed the /etc/network/interfaces on putty to obtain a static IP. Now I cannot "talk" to my Pi, because every time I start a new session on putty with the new static IP, trying to log in my Pi, putty tells me the error: connection timed out.

Now I even cannot find the dynamic IP on my routers webpage...what can I do to get everything go back to the beginning... I miss dynamic IP. Any one could help?

Comment: Word to the wise:  Next time you have things working well, use Win32DiskImager to make an image file of the SD Card so you can always revert to a known, good state.

Answer (score 2):

> This applies to Raspbian Wheezy prior to 2015-05-05 for later (and Jessie) See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

The default settings in /etc/network/interfaces should be something like

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp
```

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/29806/8697

NOTE It is standard practice on Linux to make a copy of any system file before modifying it.

Comment: add NOTE: it should be a standard practice not only on Linux!!! ;-)